# Lotus Notes - auto reply agent for emails received into one particular mail-in

Tags: lotus-notes

I've created an auto reply agent using a simple action agent, this currently responds to all senders and I only want to sent replies to a specific set of senders.

Here's an example of what I would like to achieve:

I have a Lotus Notes mail-in database with the email address: `inquiries@estateexports.com`.

I've created an email alias to this mail-in database: `order@estateexports.com`.

I only want to send an auto reply to senders who email `order@estateexports.com`.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

When you create the agent, click on the 'Document Selection' in the pane on the left side of the designer, then click on the 'Add Condition' button at the bottom.  This will bring up the 'Add Condition' dialog.  Fill it out as follows:

- Condition = 'By field'
- Field = 'SendTo'
- Operator = 'Contains'
- Value = 'order@estateexports.com'